# The definite article before the word "election"

Tags: articles

Tell me please which of the following sentences is correct:

> 1. It allowed for the election of senators.
> 2. It allowed for election of senators.

I thing the first one is correct because "senators" modifies "election", so " the" is needed. But I have seen it being used without "the". So if the is not needed, explain it for me please why.

Comment: You are correct, and "the" is expected -- but I think this is more because "allow for election" doesn't *feel* idiomatic, than because of any rule.  Although if you have seen it then it must feel idiomatic to some people.

Comment: You say you've seen the second one. [I'm not sure I believe you.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+allowed+for+election+of+senators%22).

Comment: Yes I have seen if in crash course politics and govermnent

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope  then the course materials might be in error.  Sometimes editors don't proofread everything, and even good software might not be able to detect this kind of grammatical error.  It's a credit to your English skill that you spotted it and thought it weird.

Comment: I'd have to see more context to make a ruling. Depending on the preceding sentences, it might be fine without the article: _For more than two centuries, senators were appointed, not elected. Sovereigns decide who would represent the people. But the new constitution changed all that – it allowed for election of senators, rather than handpicked cronies_. I think it reads a little better with the article, but you'd have a hard time convincing me that the article omission is both incorrect and jarring.